# OSX: Why does curl not use Automatic Proxy Configuration / PAC?

Tags: macos, curl, proxy, pac

My workplace has a fairly complicated [PAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_auto-config) file for determining which proxy HTTP(S) traffic should use to get to various internal and external networks. This is fine for Chrome, Safari, etc., but awful for commandline tools (`curl`, most scripting language HTTP libraries). The normal solution is set various environment variables like `HTTP_PROXY` to `proxy.example.com:8888`, but that doesn't work with PAC. Instead, most of us run some kind of PAC-aware proxy on `localhost` and send everything through that.

My question is, why is any of this necessary in the first place? OSX is fine evaluating PAC rules for its own connections, but `curl`, etc. can't? `networksetup` gives me this:

```
$ networksetup -listallhardwareports
Hardware Port: Wi-Fi
Device: en0
Ethernet Address: ...
$ networksetup -getproxyautodiscovery Wi-Fi
Auto Proxy Discovery: On
```

I took that to mean that anything going through `en0` should have proxy auto-discovery. Is that wrong? Does proxy auto-discovery and auto-configuration take place at a higher level that's only accessible through Apple APIs (which browsers, etc. use)? (And if so, how can I access them?)

Comment: I couldn't tell you why the functionality is the way you describe (it's been that way seemingly for years). There is a way to have a [script](https://github.com/macmule/setAutomaticProxyConfigurationURL) do all the heavy lifting though for use with terminal, etc. that will work with pac files. There is [one issue](https://github.com/macmule/setAutomaticProxyConfigurationURL/issues/1) that you'll probably need to address before it's compatible with the latest OS X though.

Comment: @AndrewO, we have this same issue. Can you share a bit more specifics on the PAC-aware proxy on localhost solution you use? I searched for a few OS X proxy applications, but have not been able to find one that is PAC-aware.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OS X 10.11 and up include `nscurl`, which is a simplified curl-like utility that uses the platform APIs for network transfer. I would expect it to support proxies as well as any OS X app, although it doesn't have all the features of full `curl`

Comment: Thanks. It's closer than I was before, but not quite there. As you mentioned, it's not a complete drop-in replacement for `curl` or `libcurl`. Even if it was, lots of stuff would have to be relinked or recompiled (to say nothing of outliers like Java).

But it does provide a hint to my suspicion that these features are only available through Apple APIs like Core Foundation or AppKit (further evidence [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/ChoosingTheRightNetworkingAPI/ChoosingTheRightNetworkingAPI.html)).